# Defining Surjection as an Implication

Tags: functions, logic, definition

Is the following logical notation valid in describing the condition for a function $f$ being surjective? If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a function, then $f$ is surjective if

$$\forall y, \exists x \in A \, : \, y \in B \implies y=f(x)$$

I think it is valid, because it seems equivalent to the traditional definition of surjection where the implication is implicit in the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A = B = \emptyset$, the empty function $f = \emptyset \subseteq A \times B$ is a surjection of $A$ onto $B$, but your formula:

$$\forall y \exists x \in A (y \in B \implies y=f(x))$$

which means

$$\forall y \exists x (x \in A \land (y \in B \implies y=f(x)))$$

is false in that case. You need to say:

$$\forall y (y \in B \implies (\exists x \in A (y=f(x))))$$

which is equivalent to the short-hand form:

$$\forall y \in B \exists x \in A (y=f(x))$$

(which is what I think you had in mind when you referred to the "traditional definition" with implicit implications).

Comment: There, no need to be even mildly irritated.

Comment: Sorry for the friction. It seemed initially that you were arguing against "$f$ is a surjection \implies \forall y[...]$", but OP only asks about the converse, where fewer subtleties arise.

Comment: And rereading the question now, ... right, "equivalent" does suggest OP actually intends "iff". Anyway, best to write it sensibly, as you did, and then "iff" really does hold.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's valid. It's equivalent to the usual definition:

$$
\text{$f: A \rightarrow B$ is a surjection} \iff \forall y \in B, \exists x \in A : y = f(x)
$$

Anytime you have

"$\forall y, y \in S \implies \text{something about $y$}$"

it's the same as

"$\forall y \in S, \text{something about $y$}$"

I think that one may be defined in terms of the other, deep down in the bowels of whatever set theory you're using.

Comment: What if $A = B = \emptyset$? There is an existential quantifier involved here that means your "anytime you have $\ldots$ it's the same as $\ldots$" reasoning doesn't apply (you can't arbitrarily move $y \in S$ inside the existential quantifier).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is equivalent (**edit** if you assume that $A$ is not empty, as Rob Arthan pointed out) although someone could complain on the fact it would be more natural to write it as 
$$\forall y (y \in B \Rightarrow \exists x (x \in A \land f(x)=y))$$

The difference is psycological more than logical and stands in the fact that your form becomes in natural language: *for each $y$ there is an $x \in A$ such that*

- $y \in B$ *and* $y=f(x)$;
- *or* $y \not \in B$ (and $x$ can be any element of $A$, $f(x)=y$ won't be ever verified but that's not a problem because the left part in the implication is false).

The form I wrote above instead becomes (in natural language):
*for all $y$ if $y \in B$ then there is an $x \in A$ such that $y=f(x)$*.

P.s.: Now I'm wondering on whether these two formulas are equivalent in construtive mathematics.

Comment: Certainly your argument is not constructive as you are using the law of the excluded middle: either $y \in B$ or $y \not\in B$.

Comment: Note also that you are assuming $A \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @RobArthan cool I didn't notice that, thanks.